# Why is my "For" statement being ignored? And how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

Python is completely ignoring the "For statemnt" after every "Elif or Else" Statements, I have debugged it by putting printing lines inside them, Printed nothing, I put printing lines outside the for statement and inside the Elif statements, Printed stuff, I have searched along and i'm not sure what to do.

Why is my "for" statement being ignored? And how to fix it/

```
def horizental_checker(lst1,lst2,lst3,lst4,place_checker,lst5=[],lst6=[],lst7=[]):     #place_checker checks if the lst is before the fourth column
count = 0
if place_checker == 1 or place_checker == 20:
    for a,b,c,d in zip(lst1,lst2,lst3,lst4):
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        c = int(c)
        d = int(d)
        return (a * b * c * d)
elif place_checker == 2 or place_checker == 19:
    print "TESSSSSST"

    for e,a,b,c,d in zip(lst5,lst1,lst2,lst3,lst4):
        print a,b,c,d,e
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        c = int(c)
        d = int(d)
        e = int(e)
        count = (a * b * c * d)
        print "my count is %i" % count
        if (e * a * b * c) > count:
            count = (e * a * b * c)
            print "my second count is %i" % count
        return count

elif place_checker == 3 or place_checker == 18:
    for e,f,a,b,c,d in zip(lst5,lst6,lst1,lst2,lst3,lst4):
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        c = int(c)
        d = int(d)      
        count = (a * b * c * d)
        if (e * a * b * c) > count:
            count = (e * a * b * c)
        if (f * e * a * b) > count:
            count = (f * e * a * b)
        return count        
else:
    for e,f,g,a,b,c,d in zip(lst5,lst6,lst7,lst1,lst2,lst3,lst4):
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
        c = int(c)
        d = int(d)      
        count = (a * b * c * d)
        if (e * a * b * c) > count:
            count = (e * a * b * c)
        if (f * e * a * b) > count:
            count = (f * e * a * b)
        if (g * f * e * a) > count:
            count = (g * f * e * a)
        return count
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: indention is fixed on editor, It's not fixed here though - the for loop doesn't even start, I want it to check if place_checker == 1, if place_checker = 1, gets the first element from each 4 lists, and multiplies them together then returns the highest result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is zip(...) returning?  The body won't have anything to execute if it's returning an empty list.  print out what zip(...) is returning before the for.

Comment: Ouch, That seemed to be the problem, Thanks!

Comment: well if he finds out the zip return value then his problem is solved.  One of the inputs used in the zip is empty so the for has nothing to execute.  Since he put prints in the body, the zip returning empty is the only possibility.

Comment: Who's down voting this so much, it was the correct answer.  Please up vote this.